# Settings for Cmder (conemu) minimize to tray

Tags: conemu, cmder

Where to find the settings than when I close the terminal from here

[image]

to force it to close actually instead of being minimized to tray?

Comment: Try the icon  _  left of the X

Comment: well that will minimize too, but I don't want to minimize at all, just to be closed (removed) from the tray

Comment: The X will close it - It does so for ALL properly behaved apps.

Comment: Some apps need to go File Exit or set an option not to minimize.  Check all the options in your app to close. There is no App harmony on how to close.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > General > Task Bar. Uncheck "always show TSA icon" and "auto minimize to TSA". TSA stands for taskbar status area.